# Not getting AutomationElement.FocusedElement from internet explorer

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, automation

> Blockquote

```
if (param.Action == EventActions.KP || param.Action == EventActions.KU || param.Action == EventActions.KD)
{
point = new System.Windows.Point(cursorPos.X, cursorPos.Y);
element = AutomationElement.FocusedElement;
}
```

I have written code to get Key press events from internet explorer. But sometimes 
**AutomationElement.FocusedElement** generates error and not returning element.